# Why flexviews test_demo changelog table not created

Tags: database, view, centos, mariadb, materialized

I testing materialized view for the MariaDB which is flexviews. I'm using a CentOS latest version. I refered

https://www.percona.com/blog/2011/03/25/using-flexviews-part-two-change-data-capture/

In the reference, at the step below, no table with the name “flexviews.test_demo was found to be created.

```
mysql> select * from flexviews.test_demo\G
```

Up to that point(following the above reference), every step were done successfully except sometimes the following step generated multiple rows.

```
$ mysql -e 'select * from flexviews.binlog_consumer_status\G' -uroot -p
```

What could I have done wrong?

One more thing here, instead of having test_demo table, I found mvlog_d04c... table created with the content shown(see below figure). Is this normal?

[image]

Comment: I think that is normal after I watched this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WhkHMkY80nQ